# Using MonthLocator + ConciseDateFormatter, how can I make the labels for years in bold?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a Gantt chart using matplotlib, after populating the plot with data spanning over several years and fiddeling with the x-axis like so:

```py
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=mdates.MO))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(
    mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(mdates.AutoDateLocator())
)

ax.set_xlim(MIN_DATE, MAX_DATE)
ax.xaxis.remove_overlapping_locs = False
```

I get a decent x-axis, with the major ticks being the months and the minor ticks the weeks, and every new year, the label for the month is replaced with the year.

[image: X-Axis with Years and Months]

The problem is now, that the year labels are a bit hard to spot. My question is, is it possible to get the years in **bold** just so they stand a bit out from the months?